# How can activity call a method inside fragment created dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity which creates fragments using the following code

```
private void launchFragment(int pos)
{
    Fragment f = null;
    String title = null;
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        title = "Friends";
        f = new FriendList();
    }
    else if (pos == 2)
    {
        title = "Notes";
        f = new NoteList();
    }
    else if (pos == 3)
    {
        title = "Projects";
        f = new ProjectList();
    }
    else if (pos == 5)
    {
        title = "About";
        f = new AboutUs();
    }
    else if (pos == 6)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
        finish();
    }
    if (f != null)
    {
        while (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, f).addToBackStack(title)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of a fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_chat, null);

    loadConversationList();

    contactName = this.getArguments().getString("contactusername");

    contactId = this.getArguments().getString("contactid");


    ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adp = new ChatAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adp);
    list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    list.setStackFromBottom(true);

    txt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

    setTouchNClick(v.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera));
    setTouchNClick(v.findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
    return v;
}
```

I want to call a method in above fragment class. I was not able to do this as I have not given id of the fragment in the XML file. I am not loading the static fragment using XML. Therefore, I don't have Id.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896948/how-to-call-method-inside-the-fragment-from-activity-where-fragment-dynamically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070215/call-activity-method-from-fragment) questions on the StackOverFlow, but they are not solving my problem.

Kindly help if anyone knows how to tackle this scenario.

Comment: Do you have that mathod in all fo your fragments or you want to call that method only in one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make all your fragments implement an interface. This interface will return a String (for example) which will identify your fragment, and then cast your fragment to it after getting the fragment using `findFragmentById()` as follows:

Create your interface

```
 public interface IFragmentName
 {
    public String getFragmentName();
 }
```

Implement your interface (for example in `NoteList`)

```
public NoteList extends Fragment implements IFragmentName
{
   //Do your stuff...
   public String getFragmentName()
   {
       return "NoteList";
   }

}
```

After this get your current fragment from your activity

```
IFragmentName myFragment = (IFragmentName) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
```

Finally check your `getFragmentName()` value and cast to the fragment you want:

```
if(myFragment.getFragmentName().equals("NoteList")
{
   NoteList myNoteListFragment = (NoteList) myFragment;
   myNoteListFragment.callMyMethod(); //here you call the method of your current Fragment.
}
```

I have coded these snippets without any IDE so maybe I have missed a semicolon or something like that :)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, you are super fast... let me try them in a moment... Thanks  :)

Comment: It was superb man, thanks again... I searched lot of Internet but could not find this solution... I marked the answer as best and also gave you a vote :)

Comment: There is one problem why does it returns null to myFragment... I checked in docs, it said getFragmentById returns fragment or null, why it is not able to find the content_frame fragment.

Comment: In my xml of activity, content_frame is id of the FrameLayout, it is used to put the fragments there

Comment: sorry, i just realized that I am using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). Kindly, also update the answer so that anyone else will not get into confusion...

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late for the party. But this will be useful for others.

If at all you are using ViewPager to render the fragment use this code in your parent Activity.

[Check Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389657/5629056)